# Cannot change readahead value in linux

Tags: linux, vertica

I am new to Linux and I am trying to set the readahead value as told by this article: https://www.ca.com/us/services-support/ca-support/ca-support-online/knowledge-base-articles.tec616116.html

When I try the command:

`blockdev --setra 2048 /dev/sdb`

Nothing happens. I've also tried with sudo. When I run `blockreport` I always get this report:

[image]

So I also tried `blockdev --setra 2048 /dev/sr0` since that seems to be the device name, but then I get the error "device sr0 not found".

Do you know what I am doing wrong when trying to set the readahead value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A restart of the system was required to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

/dev/sr0 is a device on the scsi controller. /dev/cdrom is a symlink to either /dev/sr0 or /dev/hdc or whichever block device is appropriate.

I think you are trying to change RA for which the actual medium is not present.